# Why am I getting error while setting up cron job in magento?

Tags: magento, cron

1. 2013-06-24T08:39:26+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /var/www/magento-ext/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php on line 68
2. 2013-06-24T08:39:26+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Neev/Setattribute/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/magento-ext/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
3. 2013-06-24T08:39:26+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Neev/Setattribute/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/magento-ext/app/code/local:/var/www/magento-ext/app/code/community:/var/www/magento-ext/app/code/core:/var/www/magento-ext/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/magento-ext/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
4. 2013-06-24T08:39:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Neev/Setattribute/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/magento-ext/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
5. 2013-06-24T08:39:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Neev/Setattribute/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/magento-ext/app/code/local:/var/www/magento-ext/app/code/community:/var/www/magento-ext/app/code/core:/var/www/magento-ext/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/magento-ext/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

**Magento 1.7**

Comment: Can you explain more details?

Comment: This looks like a Magento support question rather than a programming question. You should post somewhere on Magento's support resources.

Answer (score 0):

your system is obviously trying to load an observer class which can not be found by the system, hence the attempt to load it from Mage/Neev, which is part of magentos fallback system. check if there is any config.xml file which registers an event in the  section for a class with "Neev" in the name...

good luck!